# Difference between ReadAsAsync and JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json, json.net

This works for all properties:

```
string resultAsString = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiData>(resultAsString));
```

while this works only for some of them:

```
return await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<ApiData>();
```

what is the difference?

Comment: Perhaps they are using different serializers?

Answer (score 11):

The former reads *asynchronously from the stream*, and then uses a thread-pool thread to deserialize the JSON string to an object.

The latter reads asynchronously from the stream, but transforms the JSON string to an object *synchronously*, on the thread in which resumed after awaiting the asynchronous read from the stream.

Internally, both methods will utilize Json.NET to parse the data, as the extension method `HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync<T>` will internally call the [`JsonMediaTypeFormatter`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#json_media_type_formatter), which uses Json.NET.

Personally, I'd use the latter, as I see no benefit in executing the serialization on a background thread. But, test your code and see if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you for yours answer. I also thought that both methods are the same (use Json.NET). Let's strip away this async part, i still get two different results for:

`string resultAsString = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            ApiData res1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiData>(resultAsString);
`

and
`ApiData res2 = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<ApiData>();
`
I'm using JsonProperties, may this make any difference here?

Comment: `{"upstream_url":"http:\/\/localhost:34001","request_path":"\/weather","id":"a897b9cb-d4cd-4eca-ce49-42c75e71e27b","strip_request_path":true,"name":"WebFrontend","created_at":1450446815000}` this is my json. With the first method i get everything filled in, in the latter only ID and Name gets filled.

Comment: @Senj Add your class structure and JSON to the question.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov `httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<ApiData>();`
and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiData>(resultAsString)`
don't use the same deserialization mechanism

Comment: @gsubiran Did my answer help you understand the difference?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I understand your point but I'm a bit weird because I found differences in deserialization using `ReadAsAsync` and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`. If the API result have properties with spaces with first option those properties don't be deserialized even I added respective data annotations to this properties in the class. You know why this could happen?

Comment: @gsubiran I suggest opening a separate question.